# Generate new time-lagged variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I'm creating a time-series object with new variables using the transform() function in R and cannot find the proper function to calculate the difference in variable C between today and yesterday.

This is what I've got so far:

```
                 O       H       L       C  Typical Range 
2010-07-23 1092.17 1103.73 1087.88 1102.66 1098.090 15.85 
2010-07-26 1102.89 1115.01 1101.30 1115.01 1110.440 13.71  
2010-07-27 1117.36 1120.95 1109.78 1113.84 1114.857 11.17  
2010-07-28 1112.84 1114.66 1103.11 1106.13 1107.967 11.55  
2010-07-29 1108.07 1115.90 1092.82 1101.53 1103.417 23.08  
2010-07-30 1098.44 1106.44 1088.01 1101.60 1098.683 18.43
```

The next row will be added with the following function:

```
SPX <- transform(SPX, Return = (C - C(yesterday) ) / C(yesterday)))
```

Obviously, C(yesterday) is incorrect. I've tried lag(), diff() and haven't found the correct combination.

Bonus question: How do you get the Typical variable to show only to the hundreth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct function is diff if you're trying to calculate the difference of C between today and yesterday.

```
> SPX$Return <- diff(SPX$C)
> SPX
                 O       H       L       C  Typical Range Return
2010-07-23 1092.17 1103.73 1087.88 1102.66 1098.090 15.85     NA
2010-07-26 1102.89 1115.01 1101.30 1115.01 1110.440 13.71  12.35
2010-07-27 1117.36 1120.95 1109.78 1113.84 1114.857 11.17  -1.17
2010-07-28 1112.84 1114.66 1103.11 1106.13 1107.967 11.55  -7.71
2010-07-29 1108.07 1115.90 1092.82 1101.53 1103.417 23.08  -4.60
2010-07-30 1098.44 1106.44 1088.01 1101.60 1098.683 18.43   0.07
```

But it looks like you want to calculate the rate of change instead, which you can do with the ROC function from TTR.

```
> SPX$Return <- ROC(SPX$C)
> SPX
                 O       H       L       C  Typical Range        Return
2010-07-23 1092.17 1103.73 1087.88 1102.66 1098.090 15.85            NA
2010-07-26 1102.89 1115.01 1101.30 1115.01 1110.440 13.71  1.113793e-02
2010-07-27 1117.36 1120.95 1109.78 1113.84 1114.857 11.17 -1.049869e-03
2010-07-28 1112.84 1114.66 1103.11 1106.13 1107.967 11.55 -6.946068e-03
2010-07-29 1108.07 1115.90 1092.82 1101.53 1103.417 23.08 -4.167314e-03
2010-07-30 1098.44 1106.44 1088.01 1101.60 1098.683 18.43  6.354596e-05
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I've never heard of ROC() before. Nice. I was messing around with Delt() from quantmod which appears to do the same thing but was running into the same problems I'm getting with diff() and that is the following:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Diff", value = c(1.74000000000001,  : 
  replacement has 900 rows, data has 901


But ROC works fine. Hmmm.

Comment: A point of clarification: my example above uses an xts object.  The error is probably because Delt and diff don't include the leading NA for the class of object you're using (a data.frame?).

Comment: After doing a str(SPX) it does say data.frame. Hmmm, this is strange as I thought I used quantmod to download the data earlier but I've done so many changes that I lost that part of my history file, so I can't remember. It does explain the error though. I'll try it again making sure I have an xts object

Comment: Good news, I was able to find my .Rhistory file intact with how I started this problem and saved it. I started by using getSymbols("^GSPC") to get the data. I assigned to this object the name of SPX and it was at that point an xts object. BUT, when I operated the transform() function on the object, it changed into a plain vanilla data.frame object, which is why I was getting the errors with diff(). All is now well. Thanks Josh, and welcome to stackoverflow.